# How send coordinate Lat, Log for open native google map app and make router

Tags: html, phonegap

I make a app but I have four position in database. Origin: Lat and long and Destiny: Lat and long

I would like send for native google maps and make router.

How do that??

Answer (score 0):

You need Google Directions.

The Directions API is a service that calculates directions between locations. You can search for directions for several modes of transportation, including transit, driving, walking, or cycling.

Go [there](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) for more informations.

To use the Directions API, you must first activate the API in the Google Cloud Platform Console and obtain the proper authentication credentials.

You can do it [there](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/?__utma=102347093.1388565892.1567022272.1567022693.1567022693.1&__utmb=102347093.0.10.1567022693&__utmc=102347093&__utmx=-&__utmz=102347093.1567022693.1.1.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=(organic)%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=(not%20provided)&__utmv=-&__utmk=129771020&_ga=2.129412556.1500299751.1567022272-1388565892.1567022272#get-started).

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple) is a nice example of Directions Service.